# Is a legend element a grid item if a fieldset's display is grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What section of the [css-grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) specification addresses how a ***legend*** element should be handled if a ***fieldset*** element is set to **display:grid**?

As you know, a ***legend*** element is typically the first child of a ***fieldset*** element, yet rarely would anyone want it to be treated as a grid item.

I'm wondering if I need to take explicit styling-precautions to ensure that a ***legend*** element will NOT be treated as a grid item, or if the specification already has some rule (I'm overlooking) that means a ***legend*** element (by spec) is not a grid item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has changed; fieldset rendering has been siginificantly redefined and rewritten such that they may now be laid out as CSS grids. See [Mats Palmgren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350191/is-a-legend-element-a-grid-item-if-a-fieldsets-display-is-grid/65866981#65866981).

---

You won't find these details in the CSS spec, but in the HTML spec. And HTML is pretty specific about how the `fieldset` and `legend` elements should be rendered, and, for historical reasons, layout implementations for these elements is extremely rigid with very little accommodation for changes to layout modes via the `display` property.

It is for this reason that `display: grid` is simply not supported on fieldsets by any browser. In fact, [just a few days ago](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3094) there was a discussion around a proposed addition to the HTML spec to specify how the `display` property should be treated on `fieldset` and `legend` elements, and this is what's slated to be added:

> The `fieldset` element, when it generates a box (i.e., is not 'display: none' or 'display: contents'), is expected to act as follows:
>
> - ...
> - The 'display' property is expected to act as follows:
>
>   - If the computed value of 'display' is one of 'inline', 'inline-block', 'inline-table', 'ruby', 'ruby-base', 'ruby-text', 'ruby-base-container', 'ruby-text-container', 'inline-flex', or 'inline-grid', then behave as 'inline-block'.
>   - If the computed value of 'display' is one of 'block', 'table', 'table-row-group', 'table-header-group', 'table-footer-group', 'table-row', 'table-cell', 'table-column-group', 'table-column', 'table-caption', 'list-item', 'flow', 'flow-root', 'run-in', 'flex', or 'grid', then behave as 'block'.

This basically cements the current text which says that the `fieldset` element is expected to establish a block formatting context, without specifying how it should behave should a UA choose not to follow this definition.

This, coupled with the current interoperable browser behavior, means that the layout of a `legend` element will not be affected by its parent `fieldset` having `display: grid`, since its parent `fieldset` will be prevented from becoming a grid container in the first place.

Comment: why is this the case??? why dont they want us using `fieldsets` as grids?

Comment: @BugWhisperer: Fieldsets came to existence almost 2 decades before CSS grid. A lot of implementation behavior has to be set in stone in 2 years, let alone 20, because browser vendors have change inertia, and websites depend on the original behavior. Hence "historical reasons".

Comment: allowing `fieldsets` to `display` as `flex` or `grid` or whatever would be independent of that tho...? we arent talking abotu changing default styling, just allowing for other possible styles

Answer (score 6):

All major browsers support grid (and flexbox) layout on `<fieldset>` these days.  Firefox [added it back in 2015](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1230207).

By default, a rendered `<legend>` is not a child box of the [anonymous fieldset content box](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#anonymous-fieldset-content-box) (which implements the actual grid/flex layout) so it is not treated as a grid item - it behaves the same regardless of the fieldset's `display` value.

The HTML spec for [fieldset/legend rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements) now has a fairly detailed description of how the layout works, described in CSS terms.

To override the default behavior and make the `<legend>` behave as a grid item, style it with `display: contents`, documented in [the CSS Display spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#unbox-html) as such:

> Per HTML, a `<legend>` with `display: contents` is not a rendered legend, so it does not have magical display behavior. (Thus, it reacts to `display: contents` normally.)

Demo here: https://codepen.io/karlhorky/pen/LYdxQWe

Comment: Ah seems like Emil Björklund mentions a way of using `display: contents` on `legend` elements to disable this magic behavior: https://thatemil.com/blog/2017/07/01/fixing-fieldsets/

Comment: I'll edit the post above too to add a note about this